# How to install Qt version 4.8.1 in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, kubuntu, qt

How can I install Qt version 4.8.1 in Kubuntu 14.04?

I cannot find the version 4.8.1 in the official Qt site's downloads list.
Kindly help me to install the exact version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to first  download the source from  [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.1/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1.tar.gz) for qt 4.8.1.
Then open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and goto the path where you have download the file.

Install the required dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

Then extract the file using

```
tar -xvzf qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1.tar.gz
```

Then goto the extracted folder using

```
cd qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1
```

and run

1. `./configure`
2. `make`
3. `sudo checkinstall`

This will make a `.deb` of the source you can install as a normal application via `apt`

```
sudo dpkg -i path/to/output.deb
```

Change `path/to/output.deb` to the path of the created `.deb` file.

Comment: It shows "No Access" Error..!

Comment: @Rooney Thats strange it working for me.can u access this page https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.1/

Comment: You should swap the `make install` for a `check-install` it will build a .deb of the source, so it can be installed by apt as a n application, I will add it for you, but check it out for future answers, it is very good https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall +1 though

Comment: @markkirby thanks for the suggestion didnt know that

Comment: Thanks, but While running the ./configure command it shows "  You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing
 QMAKE_INCDIR_X11 and QMAKE_LIBDIR_X11 in /home/rex/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/mkspecs/linux-g++. " error ? Is it because of any missing dependencies ? @mohit_rajan

Comment: @Rooney try installing `libfontconfig1-dev`,` libfreetype6-dev`, `libx11-dev`,` libxcursor-dev`,` libxext-dev`, `libxfixes-dev`, `libxft-dev`,` libxi-dev`, `libxrandr-dev` and` libxrender-dev`