# Where is .deb file created after running the command sudo make install in qt 4.8 installation process in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, kubuntu, qt, qt-creator

Please refer to this link [How to install Qt version 4.8.1 in Kubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756897/how-to-install-qt-verion-4-8-1).

I have run

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Where is .deb file created after run the command `sudo make install` in qt 4.8 installation process so that I can complete my QT 4.8 installation? I am using Ubuntu Mate OS.

I can't understand these three lines as below in the above link:

1. This will make a .deb of the source you can install as a normal application via apt
2. `sudo dpkg -i path/to/output.deb`
3. Change path/to/output.deb to the path of the created .deb file.

I can't find the "path/to/output.deb" of created .deb file.

Please help...

Comment: `sudo make install` usually compiles source into a binary; the output being a binary executable - not a .deb file.  View the make file itself to see what it does.  Your provided link does something different to what you did. (it installs the binary itself without using deb/dpkg/apt/..)

Comment: So according to you @guiverc, after run the commands - > ./configure - > make - > sudo make install -------- Complete QT will be installed?

Comment: `make install` is different to `checkinstall` was my point; but what is built depends on the recipe in the makefile which I have not looked at. Your line in the question "*sudo make install (same as sudo checkinstall)*" seems to equate `make install` with `checkinstall` which is not valid.

Comment: okay... i have run the command "sudo make install". what should i do now????

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You seem to have chosen the difficult way… Is there any reason why you can’t simply install [`libqt4*`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt4) or [`qt4-default`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?&keywords=qt4-default) from Ubuntu repositories? The question you linked refers to Ubuntu [tag:14.04] which is outdated.

Comment: ok thanx @Melebius

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Qt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866407/how-to-install-qt)

Comment: @Melebius I think it's not a duplicate. Certainly not of that one.

Comment: @Kulfy Well, this and the target question contain unrelated requirements but they both result in installing Qt 4 using APT. And the target question has a sensible title at least… However, since this question has got a specific answer, I’m retracting my close vote.

Comment: @Melebius Yeah but if OP really followed the answer on the question they linked and wrote `checkinstall`, it would be a generic question with Qt as an example. But as @guiverc pointed, there's some uncertainty in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to compile Qt4 from source because Qt 4.8 is provided by the *qt4-default* package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install qt4-default
```

After you have installed qt4-default you can run the following command to list other available Qt4 packages:

```
apt search qt4-*
```